# Anaconda failing to solve environment

Tags: python, anaconda

** Disclaimer: I am relatively new to data science and anaconda. I have basic competency in python however, I'm no expert (took an accelerated course on the path to obtaining an applied economics major if that helps illustrate where I'm at)**

Basic Info: MacOSx (Catalina v 10.15.4), Anaconda Navigator v 1.9.12, Spyder v.4.0.1
I am still unable to install selenium on anaconda even after  trying  all of the following commands in my terminal:

- `conda install -c conda-forge selenium`
- `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 selenium`
- `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 selenium`
- `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 selenium`

Each time I try, I get this message

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. 
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \  Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  
Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining conflict for notebook anaconda jupyter_client libsodium zeromq spyder pyzmq spyder-kernels: : 325it [45:34,  1.0
Examining conflict for notebook anaconda jupyter_client libsodium zeromq spyder pyzmq spyder-kernels: : 326it [45:34,  1.4
Examining conflict for anaconda lxml: : 326it [45:37,  1.49s/it]                                                   failed                                                                          |                         

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
```

...

...

After this it lists a BUNCH of stuff that all look similar to this (this is just the first line of MANY):

`anaconda-navigator -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*']`

...

...

Things I have tried to resolve this problem:

1. `conda update conda` because I heard this might have something to do with having a python v that wasn't compatible with anaconda navigator. Update was successful but came back with the same message above
2. `pip install -U selenium` and `python setup.py install`

Please help me be able to use selenium in spyder!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you provide your current environment? Before installing selenium? `conda list` should return all the packages installed in the environment.

Comment: Don't use that pip command.  it doesn't play well with Anaconda. Have you tried simply conda install selinium?